# Como pasar los elementos de un JSON a una variable en PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Tengo este JSON y estoy intentando convertirlo a un array para poder tomar un valor especifico del Array, Pero me dice que el array no contiene el indice.
El JSON se retorna desde un API es por ello que no puedo modificarlo, Lo que necesito es tener una variable en PHP Y que ahi se guarde el identificador nombre del json que en este caso seria **MOSCA**

### Este es mi JSON

```
{
    "nombre": [
        {
            "huevecillos": 45,
            "_id": "5db9b5d04bc4d017f48ffcee",
            "nombre": "mosca",
            "ciclo": "23",
            "apariencia": "Horrible",
            "imagen": "Pendiente",
            "usuario": "Victor",
            "fecha": "October 30, 2019, 5:09 pm",
            "aplica": "Aplicacion Web",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Este es mi código en PHP

```
<?php
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
use GuzzleHttp\Client;


$client = new Client([
  'base_uri' => 'http://localhost:3000/obtenPlaga',
  'timeout'  => 5.0,
]);


$dtaCultivo=['nombre'=> 'mosca'
          ];

$res = $client->request('GET', '', ['form_params' => $dtaCultivo]);
if ($res->getStatusCode() == '200') //Verifico que me retorne 200 = OK
{
  $resultados=json_decode($res->getBody());
  echo $resultados[1];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El dato que buscas se encuentra en la siguiente ruta: `nombre[0]->nombre`

Dicho de otro modo, la propiedad `nombre` que aparece en la raíz del JSON apunta luego a un array, y en la clave `0` de ese array hay otro objeto JSON con varias propiedades, entre ellas `nombre` que contiene el dato.

Ejemplo:

```
$datos='
{
    "nombre": [
        {
            "huevecillos": 45,
            "_id": "5db9b5d04bc4d017f48ffcee",
            "nombre": "mosca",
            "ciclo": "23",
            "apariencia": "Horrible",
            "imagen": "Pendiente",
            "usuario": "Victor",
            "fecha": "October 30, 2019, 5:09 pm",
            "aplica": "Aplicacion Web",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
       ';
$json=json_decode($datos);
$nombre=$json->nombre[0]->nombre;
echo $nombre;
```

***Salida:***

```
mosca
```